# How to combine many "x AND y" conditions with OR for WHERE clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a many to many junction table similar to the following:

```
        FooBar
-----------------------
id    | foo_id | bar_id
1     |    1   |    1
2     |    1   |    2
3     |    2   |    3
4     |    3   |    4
```

and a list of `(foo_id, bar_id)`, such as:

```
items = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)
```

How can I perform the following query in SQLAlachemy?

```
SELECT id
FROM foo_bar
WHERE (foo_id = 1 AND bar_id = 1)
   OR (foo_id = 1 AND bar_id = 2)
   OR (foo_id = 2 AND bar_id = 3)
   OR (foo_id = 3 AND bat_id = 4)
```

I have attempted variations of the following, but all of them return a WHERE clause containing only ANDs

```
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_
q = session.query(FooBar)
for item in items:
    q = q.filter(or_(and_(FooBar.foo_id == item[0], FooBar.bar_id == item[1])))

print q.statement
for item in
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that a call to `or_()` with a single expression is basically just the expression, as there's nothing to OR with. Repeated calls to [`Query.filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) append new predicates combined with AND. Move the iteration over items inside the `filter(or_())`:

```
q = q.filter(or_(*(and_(FooBar.foo_id == foo_id, FooBar.bar_id == bar_id)
                   for foo_id, bar_id in items)))
```

This generates a generator expression, which is then unpacked as positional arguments to `or_()`.

If using a backend that supports composite IN construct, such as Postgresql and MySQL, you could replace this with [`tuple_().in_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_):

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_

...

q = q.filter(tuple_(FooBar.foo_id, FooBar.bar_id).in_(items))
```